# How to get folder name when dragging from Windows Explorer to Virtualtreeview in Delphi

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, virtualtreeview

I have a delphi form with a VirtualStringTree and a ComboBox (as shown below)

[image]

As shown in the image above..I need to get the folder name that I'm trying to drag from the Windows Explorer & drop on the VirtualStringTree (& I don't know how to do the Drop&Drag correctly).

& Thanks in advance!